# angularjs preserving inputs in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/LQGE2/525/

The idea is whenever an ng repeat item is updated the related inputs data is deleted. How do I get the input to not be deleted when the ng repeat item is changed?

```
function AlbumCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
  var a = 5
  var counters = [a, 100, 999];
  $scope.counters = counters
  $scope.plusOne = function (i) {
     counters[i] = counters[i] + 1
     $scope.counters = counters
  }
}


<html ng-app>
<body>
<div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in counters"  ng-click="plusOne(key)">
        {{value}}
        <button>plusone</button>
        <input/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After version 1.2 you have the option to use `track by`, that reuses DOM elements inside ng-repeat.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to store the values somehow on the AlbumCtrl's scope - for instance like that:

```
function AlbumCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    var a = 5
    var counters = [a, 100, 999];
    $scope.counters = counters
    $scope.plusOne = function (i) {
        counters[i] = counters[i] + 1
        $scope.counters = counters
    }
    $scope.inputs = {}; // <-- relevant
}
```

and then in mark-up:

```
<div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in counters">{{value}}
          <button ng-click="plusOne(key)">plusone</button>
          <input ng-model="inputs[key]" />
      </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/enmp2/)

Btw. I moved `ng-click` to button element.

Answer (score -4):

As I know - no way.
ngRepeat always re-creates items.